# .NET MAUI SQLite CreateTableAsync crashes app without exception

Tags: .net, sqlite, xamarin, maui

im currently trying to use SQLite in my MAUI Project.
I have used it before in WPF without any issues and I did it the exact same way in MAUI without success.

All of the solutions online didnt work for me, maybe someone can help me out.

Here is my code:

Im calling `createProfiles()` which calls `ProfileService.AddProfile(Profile)` which then calls `Init()`.
In `Init()` my App runs till `await db.CreateTableAsync<Profile>();` and then closes without any exception being thrown.

**ProfileService.cs**

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection db;

        async Task Init()
        {
            if (db != null)
                return;

            var databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Profiles.db");

            db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);

            await db.CreateTableAsync<Profile>();
        }

        public async Task AddProfile(Profile profile)
        {
            await Init();
            var id = await db.InsertAsync(profile);
        }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
private async void createProfiles()
        {
            Profile tempProfile = new Profile
            {
                Name = "Test",
                Hostname = "0.0.0.0",
                Port = 23,
            };

            await ProfileService.AddProfile(tempProfile);
        }
```

**Profile.cs**

```
public class Profile
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Hostname { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }

        public Profile()
        {

        }
    }
```

I have tried setting default values in the Profile constructor, without success.
I also tried wrapping `await ProfileService.AddProfile(tempProfile);` in a seperat thread, without success.

Comment: Your code contains no exception handling, so how do you know that no exception is thrown?  Have you checked the logs?

Comment: @Jason I tried putting try,catch around createTeableAsync but it doenst even go into catch.
By logs do you mean the output window? I looked at it, but unfortunately I dont understand most of it... Here are the last few lines:
```
[QT] [QT]file does not exist
[libMEOW] applied 1 plugins for [com.companyname.SP_Client_Mobile]:
[libMEOW]   plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]: 0xb400007d668df400
[libMEOW] rebuild call chain: 0xb400007d0afd4b80
[libMEOW] meow delete tls: 0xb400007d0afc5900
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader.dll
```

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo of your app so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself.
I will try to explain it for everyone who has the same issue in the future.

After looking at the Debug Log from my physical Android device I found the following etries:
[Debug entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAyZr.png)

This clearly says, that some SQLite assemblies failed to loaded.

The only thing I had to do now was:

- Unistall the app on the phone
- Add `<EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>` to my `.csproj`, to turn off Fast Deploy.

And now it all works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the guide in the microsoft [docs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green/)?
You need an additional library
[SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green/) to make sqlite-pcl-net work on each platform.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I must have missed that. But even after including the library and setting the constants nothing changed. Still the same problem :/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using these flags when creating the connection. Your output indicates your file does not exist, so maybe the flag Create might solve your issue or make sure you create the file on your own before you use other database operations.

```
public const SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
        // open the database in read/write mode
        SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite |
        // create the database if it doesn't exist
        SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
        // enable multi-threaded database access
        SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;
```

`Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path, Flags);`

Answer (score 0):

```
  public interface IProfileRepo
        {
            Task<bool> AddProfileAsync(Profile profile);    
        }    

  public class ProfileRepo : IProfileRepo
    {
      private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _connect;
            public ProfileRepo (SQLiteAsyncConnection connect)
            {
                _connect = connect;
                Task.Run(() => this.CreateTable()).Wait();
            }
    
            private async Task CreateTable()
            {
                await _connect.CreateTableAsync<Profile>();
            }
            //Other methods Add, Delete and etc.
    }

    public class UnitOfWork
        {
            private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _connect;
            private IProfileRepo _profileRepo;
            public UnitOfWork(string dbPath)
            {
                _connect = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            }
            public IProfileRepo ProfileRepo
            {
                get
                {
                    return _profileRepo = _profileRepo ?? new ProfileRepo(_connect);
                }
            }      
        }

public class ProfileService
{
        public async Task Add(Profile profile)
        {
          await App.UnitOfWork.ProfileRepo.Add(profile);
        }
}


public partial class App : Application
{
public static UnitOfWork UnitOfWork
        {
            get
            {
                if (unitOfWork == null)
                {
                    unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "TestDB.db3"));
                }
                return unitOfWork;
            }
        }
}
```

During development, you may want to drop the database every time the application starts.

```
private void DeleteLocalDB()
        {           
            var file = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "TestDB.db3");
            if(File.Exists(file))
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }            
        }
```

Used nuget package

```
 <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
```