# .NET MAUI Application hangs on CreateTableAsync

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, maui, sqlite-net

I have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFP8Np-uRWc&t=) tutorial to implement SQLite-net into my MAUI application. Whenever the program executes "await db.CreateTableAsync<Restroom>();", the whole application freezes up. I have tried several solutions, including trying to prevent deadlock with ConfigureAwait(false) as shown in [this blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), and using MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread as shown in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74249000/table-creation-is-stalling-without-throwing-exception) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74249000/table-creation-is-stalling-without-throwing-exception). Both of these threads didn't work because the solutions still called CreateTableAsync since it's inside of the InitAsync Task.
I have also tried:
-Updating all my dependencies.
-Implementing raw.bundle.green.
-Creating a whole new project to see if the issue will be replicated (it was).
-Removing the Location property of Restroom model and adjusting the code accordingly.
-Adding `<EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>` to .csproj, to turn off Fast Deploy as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75695093/22091763).
What could be the issue?

Restroom.cs

```
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dook.Model
{
    public class Restroom
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public Location PinLocation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

RestroomService.cs

```
using Dook.Model;
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dook.Services
{
    public static class RestroomService
    {
        static SQLiteAsyncConnection db;

        static async Task InitAsync()
        {
            if(db != null) 
                return;

            //Get an absolute path to the database file
            var databasePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "MyData.db");

            db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);

            await db.CreateTableAsync<Restroom>();
        }

        public static async Task AddPinAsync(string name, string address, string username, Location location)
        {
            await InitAsync();
            var test = "test";
            var restroom = new Restroom
            {
                Name = name,
                Address = address,
                Username = username,
                PinLocation = location
            };

            var id = await db.InsertAsync(restroom);
        }

        public static async Task RemovePinAsync(int id)
        {
            await InitAsync();

            await db.DeleteAsync<Restroom>(id);
        }

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<Restroom>> GetPinAsync()
        {
            await InitAsync();

            var restroom = await db.Table<Restroom>().ToListAsync();
            return restroom;
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;
using Microsoft.Maui.Maps;
using Map = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map;
using Dook.Model;
using Dook.Services;
using MvvmHelpers;
using MvvmHelpers.Commands;
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Extensions;

namespace Dook.ViewModel
{
    public partial class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableRangeCollection<Restroom> Restroom { get; set; }
        public AsyncCommand RefreshCommand { get; }
        public AsyncCommand<Location> AddCommand { get; }
        public AsyncCommand<Restroom> RemoveCommand { get; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Map Controller";


                //var restroom1 = RestroomService.GetPin().Result;
                //Restroom = restroom1 as ObservableRangeCollection<Restroom>;

            Restroom = new ObservableRangeCollection<Restroom>();

            AddCommand = new AsyncCommand<Location>(Add);
            RemoveCommand = new AsyncCommand<Restroom>(Remove);
            RefreshCommand = new AsyncCommand(Refresh);
        }

        async Task Add(Location pinlocation)
        {
            var name = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync("Location Name", "Name of Location");
           // var address = "Latitude: {pinlocation.Latitude}, Longitude: {pinlocation.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}";
            var address = "test";
            var username = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync("Username", "Username of Toilet Adder");
            Location location = pinlocation;
            if(name == null || address == null || username == null) { return; }
            await RestroomService.AddPinAsync(name, address, username, location);
            await Refresh();
        }
        
        async Task Remove(Restroom restroom)
        {
            await RestroomService.RemovePin(restroom.Id);
            await Refresh();
        }

        async Task Refresh()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Restroom.Clear();
            var restrooms = await RestroomService.GetPin();
            Restroom.AddRange(restrooms);
            IsBusy = false;
        }

        public static Location GetLocation()
        {
            try
            {
                Location location = new();
                location = Geolocation.Default.GetLastKnownLocationAsync().Result;
                if (location != null)
                    return location;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to get location: {ex.Message}");
                Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error!", ex.Message, "OK");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace Dook;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;
using Microsoft.Maui.Maps;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Map = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map;
using Dook.ViewModel;
using Dook.Model;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MoveMapLocation();
    }

    private void GoToLocation_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveMapLocation();
    }

    private void OnMapClicked(object sender, MapClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewModel = new MainViewModel();

        if(viewModel.AddCommand.CanExecute(e.Location)) 
            viewModel.AddCommand.ExecuteAsync(e.Location);
    }

    private void RefreshButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshPins();
    }

    private void MoveMapLocation()
    {
        //Function to avoid boilerplate code
        MapSpan mapSpan = new MapSpan(MainViewModel.GetLocation(), 0.01, 0.01);
        mainmap.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
    }

    private void RefreshPins()
    {
        var viewModel = new MainViewModel();

        viewModel.RefreshCommand.ExecuteAsync();
    }
}
```

Parallel Tasks Window
[image: Parallel Tasks]

Comment: What happens when you use your debugger to break the process while it's awaiting `CreateTableAsync`? What does the Parallel Tasks window show? (Also, you should add the suffix `...Async` to all of your `async Task`-returning methods).

Comment: I see your updated screenshot - you need to enable "Show external code"

Comment: Sorry about that - I'm very new to coding with SQLite so I wasn't really sure what the parallel stacks window has. Also, I wasn't able to press continue when debugging the program when I hit the line with CreateTableAsync.  I'm probably missing something or misunderstanding something, but I tried looking around for places with no Async suffix for the async Task-returning methods and I can't seem to find them.

Comment: He is suggesting you name YOUR async methods with an async suffix

Comment: Ah I see, thank you.

Comment: I took a quick-look at the `SQLiteAsyncConnection.CreateTableAsync`  method source on github and it's a "poor-man's async"-method that's implemented by running _non-async_ (synchronous) code in the thread-pool ([via `WriteAsync`](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/e8a24a8b2ecb4fd700c5fe46062239a9b08472fd/src/SQLiteAsync.cs#L362)) by [using `return Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/e8a24a8b2ecb4fd700c5fe46062239a9b08472fd/src/SQLiteAsync.cs#L320) - but even-so, that should still work - so I'm stumped, I'll admit.